# In EXCEL, how to get all combinations of numbers that where the sums fall within a certain range?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new here and was hope one of you geniuses can help me.

Note, this topic is similar to some out there, but none have answered this exact question.

As an excel user I have a column of numbers, say

5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 14, 17

and what to know all the combinations of sums that fall, for example, within the 25 - 35 range.

There is one more restriction: I want the combinations to be as small as possible, but still within the range.

so 17 + 9 = 26 is good
but 17 + 9 + 5 = 31 is bad (should not be counted) because the group is larger than necessary although it still is within the range.

So overall, I want to get all the possible combinations of numbers in a column that sum to fall within a specific range where the sums are as small as possible, but still within the range.

Hope anyone can help! VBA solutions are welcome - I suspect this is the only way to go.

CHeers and have a wonderful weekend!!

Comment: *"VBA solutions are welcome"* - Please, you cannot simply post your specification here and wait for someone to post a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) well if the solution exists then why can I not most kindly request help? I cannot be the first who struggles with this stuff. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: @Ferdinand Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a "please code for me" place. This is a "I have this problem with this code, I've been struggling with, but can't seem to find out, what I'm doing wrong" place. You should make an attempt to work this out yourself first - for example, read tutorials on Excel. They are in abundance, free, just google it. We will gladly help you, if you get stuck, but we are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Ferdinand because you should try to find your solution first for yourself. Only when you are stuck, then come here again and ask very specifically. By the way, your problem is called a **KNAPSACK PROBLEM**. This is very well-known and you find algorithms everywhere in the net. Come on! You are intelligent enough to formulate a problem, so I'm sure you will come to a conclusion by yourself ;)

Comment: ok. Well I have absolutely no idea how to code and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. This is apparently not the forum for that, which is ok.

Comment: @SQLPolice so arrogant. No it is not the knapsack problem - but a variation thereof. Again I am not interested in the sums adding to a specific value, but in sums adding to a specific range of values. But Im sure you knew that ;) yes there are tons of stuff out there on the knapsack problem (and the subset sum problem), but I am looking for something different, which led me here. Thanks for all your amazing help!

Comment: @Ferdinand Please, I feel it arrogant to expect that people will help you always for free. People will help you. But this forum is made for mutual exchange between IT professionals. If you want help, then you must first give it a try yourself. And when you are stuck, then write here and show what you have done. Then people will help you. But if you want a programmer to write all code for your problems, then this is called an order, and you simply need to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use SumIf(S) and give the criteria you want. it will sum you only numbers within the given range. If I understand your question well

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. The problem is that I want ALL the possible combinations of numbers that fall within my range. I dont think the SumIf function will achieve this.